# htaccess https off condition

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have created the below condition:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(shop|delivery-checkout|delivery-order|delivery-offer|confirm-sms-code|show-delivery-product|auto-search-product|add-product|update-product|remove-product|destroy-cart|get-cart|cuisine|og-shop) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|website|shop_files|shop_list|client|favicon\.ico|style\.css|sitemap.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L]

AddCharset utf-8 .js
```

What I am basically trying to do is check if (https) is not present in URL.
So except URLs referred, rewrite it to `https://www.`

**Note**: I am loading those urls: **domain.com/shop, domain.com/delivery-checkout, domain.com/delivery-order** inside an iframe and that is why I want those excluded and secure or not depending on parent site.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(shop|delivery-checkout|delivery-order) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: I am still getting a blank page inside the iframe. If I commnet those lines it works fine. Also, shop uri can be something like this: domain.com/shop/1123441241 . I do not know if this worth mentioning.

Comment: This URL is not accessible like that. It is loading in an iframe. So if the iframe has https it loads with https. If the iframe has http it loads with http. Right now using your conditions it gives a blank page. So the idea is load every page with https except the URLs mentioned(shop, delivery-checkout, ..., ...) if https is off.

Comment: Just tested and it changes to https.

Comment: Ok @anubhava, I pasted full htaccess file. I appreciate your help so far.

Comment: I commented the Rule and Condtition. Using `http://www.domain.com/index.php/shop/12412341234` turns to https. Testing the htaccess gives me "This condition was not met" for the excluded URIs.

Comment: You are right. In that case my original code worked fine also now that I am testing it on tester. Do you know how can I insect re directions?

Comment: what do the RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off ?? should it not be "on" instead of "off" ??